# How to combine 2 javascript codes in one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, combinations, visibility

I have somehow assembled 2 single codes (absolute beginner) and try to combine the two code blocks in one.

I tried the following: As soon as I scroll down, the navigation should be hidden and when I scroll up, it should appear again.

Additional: As soon as you move the mouse over it (.nav-visibility), the navigation should appear again and disappear again when mouseout. -> but only if you have scrolled down!

Problem: When you're scrolling down, the navigation disappears = which is great. But as soon as you scroll up again, it doesn't appear anymore.

```
var zero = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "0", $(window).scrollTop() >
      zero);
    zero = $(window).scrollTop();
  })
})
```

```
$('nav').mouseover(function() {
  $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "1");
  $('.nav-visibility').css("visibility", "visible");
});

$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "0");
  $('.nav-visibility').css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

Comment: This is hardly surprising since your code simply makes the nav invisible (opacity 0) in response to *any* scroll event.

Comment: Also I am not sure what the `zero` variable is doing - you are using it in a 3rd parameter passed to `.css`, but I have never used more than 2 parameters, and can't find any mention of a 3rd parameter in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: `$('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ? "0" : "1")`

Comment: thank's for the response! in this case, the nav only appears when you at the very top of the website, which is actually much better, but unfortunately it disappears forever, when i hover once on the nav... i guess there's a conflict between the 2 codes

Comment: Yes, I was responding to your "problem:" statement.  To include the other code, you need to add the `visibility` code to the scroll event (or remove from the mouse event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem 1: When you're scrolling down, the navigation disappears = which is great. But as soon as you scroll up again, it doesn't appear anymore.

This is because the `zero` point is being reset on each scroll:

```
zero = $(window).scrollTop();
```

as you want this at the top only, there's no need to reset the zero point.

There's also an issue with the call to `.css` which, with this usage, only takes 2 arguments - so the 2nd needs to be "0" or "1" based on the scroll position, giving:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ? "0" : "1");
  })
})
```

> Problem 2: the nav disappears forever, when I hover once on the nav

In this case, the hover code is not just changing the `opacity`, but also the `visibility` - so the scroll changes the opacity back, but not the visibility, leaving it invisible.

Depending on your requirements, you can remove the visibility part so that both scroll and hover make the same changes:

```
$('nav').mouseover(function() {
  $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "1");
});

$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "0");
});
```

Of course, if you un-hover when it's at the top it will also disappear, so you can add that check:

```
$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "0");
  }
});
```

Comment: amazing! it works like a charm. 1 small question: how do i do the same thing for the bottom?

i tried with the following code, but unfortunately doesn't work...:

`$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
  $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "1");
   }
});`

Comment: @jkr137 you should try debugging to find out what's going on - either in the browser debugger, or, possibly, with scroll events, using `console.log()` to see what each of the values are and why they don't add up

Comment: @MarcoS already accepted and thank you for your great support and contribution

Comment: @freedomn-m thank's again for your nice answer! ok, i will give it a try again...